# DC/DC overvoltage problem

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, maximum-ratings, ripple

I am using a 12V to +-5V [NMH1205DC](http://power.murata.com/data/power/ncl/kdc_nmh.pdf) converter. When I measure the output voltage without a load, it measures about +-8V. This converter will power a low current circuit that contains several OpAmps. Their maximum voltage ratings are +-5.5V. I am afraid that this overvoltage from the converter might kill the OpAmps. Is that a problem? How to fix it?

When I clamp the outputs with 1k load resistor, the voltage drops to +-5.2V. Is that an acceptable solution?

Also, page 4 suggests how to reduce output ripple. They provide a the table of suggested values for a 5mV p-p max ripple, and for my part those are 47uH and 4.7uF. If I want to reduce the ripple even further, say to 1mV p-p or 500uV p-p, which values should I use?

Comment: Have you seen the "Minimum load" note on page 3 of the datasheet?

Comment: Is picking a different op-amp not an option? There's lots of op-amps out there that can take higher power voltages.

Comment: @ThePhoton I wanted to quickly make up a protoboard from the components I have on hand.

Comment: N.B. The answers below ignored the ripple-reduction (part of your) question... Probably because of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246328/dealing-with-bundle-omnibus-list-of-questions-question-that-consists-of-rather-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opamp death is likely if Vmax is 5.5V and you may get 8V.

If you "have on hand" any sort of voltage reference and an opamp, or a clamp regulator (eg TL431 etc) or ... you could implement a dynamic output load that is set to just below V_max_allowed. This would clamp when needed and not when not. Even a zener diode may suffice but voltage-current curve is a bit soft.

As an example - a TL431 + 2 resistors would work.
Depending on where you are this may be quick and easy or not.

A TO92 TL431 costs $US0.28 in 1's in stock Digikey.
[**datasheet here](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000986.pdf)

These are rated at 100 mA max and 200 C/W Tja in TO92 package.
For say 50C rise you get 250 mW or about 50 mA clamping at 5V = more than enough.

If you have any dependable reference voltage you can do the same thing with 'any old opamp' (LM358/LM324 ...) and a small transistor.

Ripple reduction would probably be achieved as a bonus if you set the clamp to always operate with at least some load.

---

Added:

Zener diodes are a very movable feast indeed, and it pays to check what they claim to do in applications where it matters. The curves below are for MCC 500 mW through hole DO-35 package zeners.
Nominal value is specified at 20 mA.
IF the left hand axis is true logarithmic then the divisions are at ... 1 2.15 4.6 10 ... mA
YMMV.

From 1 mA up the 5V1 zener is relatively well behaved, giving about 4.95V at 1 mA (or 1 mA at 4.95V depending on which parameter you care about) rising to about 5.05V at 10 mA.
Swap to a 5V6 zener and you reach the op-amp abs-max Vcc of 5.5 V at only about 1 mA.

A 5V zener would do a moderately good job of taking the edge off the converters unloaded-over voltage urges in this context.

Note carefully that zeners tend to be very loosely specified at all except rated Vz and Iz and maybe there too. For these devices [**the daatasheet advises**](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/1N5221-1N5267(DO-35).pdf) that an A suffix part is 10% tolerance, B suffix is 5% and C suffix is 2% - so it can matter greatly.
[**Buy one from Digikey**](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1N5231B-TP/1N5231B-TPTR-ND/950350) at 1.8c/10000 and you'll probably get a B suffix part if you don't check. Could be worse.  Buy [the Fairchild part](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1N5231BTR/1N5231BFSCT-ND/1532765) for 12 cents in 1's and you'll find that [the datasheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/1N/1N5231B.pdf) tells you much less. It may be much the same, but who can say for ure? If your opamp relies on it you could be in trouble.
I'd use [**a TL431 clamp regulator**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431a.pdf) or similar - either directly if dissipation was OK, or driving a jellbean external transistor.

http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/1N5221-1N5267(DO-35).pdf

[image]

Comment: Good point!  Since this is a "minimum load" problem, perhaps a zener could work straight across the output without a resistor.  Just make good and sure that the zener voltage is higher than the rated output and lower than the opamps' max input.  Then the resistor that normally goes with a zener regulator is not needed because it only takes so much current (the minimum load) to pull the supply down to where it's supposed to be.

Comment: @RusselMcMahon I just tried two [1N5231B](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/345/1n52xxb-24434.pdf), and they gave me +-5.11V without load: good enough for me. Since the specsheet is not very descriptive, how should I use the data from the table to estimate... current, or other important values? For best performance, should I use zener approach or the volt. reference with a power opamp approach?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is an appropriate DC-DC converter to use when you have only 10% to play with between nominal and absolute maximum. A better converter may guaranteed the voltage to remain below 5.5V but this one does not, even with a 10% minimum load it can be 10% above nominal (right at your absolute maximum) and then add line regulation..

The 8.0V problem is due to insufficient minimum load, but even with the minimum load I think you're too close for comfort (it's caused by a simple circuit in the DC-DC converter in combination with leakage inductance in the transformer- and no opto feedback loop at all - semi-regulated by looking at the reflected voltage on the transformer).

If you want to use this DC-DC converter perhaps you could reduce the output voltage to 3.3V or 4.0V with an LDO regulator and run the op-amps from that (watch the maximum input voltage on the LDO, many are only good for 6V). That would also probably give you better results because the LDO will remove some of the noise on the DC-DC converter.

Comment: This converter is at hand and I just want to quickly build a bread board circuit to try the opamps. Would it be ok to use mentioned in the question "clamp load resistors" to avoid the high voltage?  Let's say I will load both + and - outputs to a 20% of the maximum load, which is 40mA each. Then I need 5V/40mA=125 Ohm resistors. Is that Ok?

Comment: You'll almost certainly get away with it in practice, especially for a one-off test at room temperature. The data sheet does not guarantee you'll be okay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you look on page 3 under "Application Notes - Minimum Load" it says you need to have at least 10% of the full rated load to meet the output specs in the datasheet, so you may want to decrease the resistance to 250 ohms.

Comment: Alas as Spehro Pefhany notes above, the output spec (even after you comply with the minimum load req.) does not say the voltage will be exactly +-5V... but may vary by 10% (p.2 in the spec) so you could get 5.5V... and that's before you add the max 200mV pp ripple noise, which may add another 100mV to that, thus having 5.6V peaks. If he's lucky and the converter is closer to the typical values, then those "boosts" are only 3% and respectively 75mV, so 5.15V + 0.075 = 5.225V which may be okay... for a one-off prototype where you measure the given DC-DC converter precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Originally a comment.  On second thought, it deserves an answer:

Since this is a "minimum load" problem, perhaps a zener could work straight across the output without a resistor. Just make good and sure that the zener voltage is higher than the rated output and lower than the opamps' max input. Then the resistor that normally goes with a zener regulator is not needed because it only takes so much current (the minimum load) to pull the supply down to where it's supposed to be.